# Pandas 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm working in pandas doing pivot tables and when doing the groupby (to count distinct observations) 
`aggfunc={"person":{lambda x: len(x.unique())}}` gives me the following error:
`'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'`
 any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: can you try: `aggfunc={"person":pd.Series.nunique}`

Answer (score 43):

DataFrames do not have that method; columns in DataFrames do:

```
df['A'].unique()
```

Or, to get the names with the number of observations (using the DataFrame given by closedloop):

```
>>> df.groupby('person').person.count()
Out[80]: 
person
0         2
1         3
Name: person, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what about df.describe,info? fillna?

Comment: Is there a way to `apply` a Series method to columns of a dataframe?  I was trying `df.apply(pd.Series.is_unique)`, for example, but this throws an  `AssertionError`.  Thank you.

Comment: @Confounded `df.apply(lambda x: x.is_unique)`

Answer (score 8):

Rather than removing duplicates during the pivot table process, use the `df.drop_duplicates()` function to selectively drop duplicates.

For example if you are pivoting using these `index='c0'` and `columns='c1'` then this simple step yields the correct counts.

In this example the 5th row is a duplicate of the 4th (ignoring the non-pivoted `c2` column

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'c0':[0,1,0,1,1], 'c1':[0,0,1,1,1], 'person':[0,0,1,1,1], 'c_other':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['c0','c1','person'])
pd.pivot_table(df2, index='c0',columns='c1',values='person', aggfunc='count')
```

This correctly outputs

```
c1  0  1
c0      
0   1  1
1   1  1
```

Answer (score 4):

One very easy solution to get the unique combinations of >1 columns from a DF is the following:

```
unique_A_B_combos = df[['A', 'B']].value_counts().index.values
```

Comment: just a note: this returns a numpy array as opposed to a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

```
df[['col1', 'col2']].nunique()
```

Try this instead of separate function

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to know the unique values existant in the WHOLE `DataFrame` (all columns included) you can use:

```
import numpy as np

...

np.unique(df.values)
```