# Data slicing a pandas frame - I'm having problems with unique

Tags: pandas

I am facing issues trying to select a subset of columns and running `unique` on it.

Source Data:

```
df_raw = pd.read_csv('data/master.csv', nrows=10000)
df_raw.shape()
```

Produces:

```
(10000, 86)
```

Process Data:

```
df = df_raw[['A','B','C']]
df.shape()
```

Produces:

```
(10000, 3)
```

Furthermore, doing:

```
df_raw.head()
df.head()
```

produces a correct list of rows and columns.

However,

```
print('RAW:',sorted(df_raw['A'].unique()))
```

works perfectly

Whilst:

```
print('PROCESSED:',sorted(df['A'].unique()))
```

produces:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

What am I doing wrong? If the shape and head output are exactly what I want, I'm confused why my processed dataset is throwing errors. I did read [Pandas 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244549/pandas-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-unique) on SO which correctly states that unique needs to be applied to columns which is what I am doing.

Comment: I am highly doubtful of the fact that `df['A']` resulted in a dataframe. Did you instead do `df[['A']]`?

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace error message?

Comment: Is your dataframe a df with multilevel columns?

Comment: AARGH. I had copied the same column twice intro "df" - that was the source of the error (why exactly, I don't know). I'll post it as an answer. My apologies - with 86 columns it gets confusing.

Answer (score 2):

This was a case of a duplicate column. Given this is proprietary data, I abstracted it as 'A', 'B', 'C' in this question and therefore masked the problem. (The real data set had 86 columns and I had duplicated one of those columns twice in my subset, and was trying to do a unique on that)

My problem was this:

```
df_raw = pd.read_csv('data/master.csv', nrows=10000)
df = df_raw[['A','B','C', 'A']] # <-- I did not realize I had duplicated A later.
```

This was causing problems when doing a `unique` on 'A'

Answer (score 0):

From the entire dataframe to extract a subset a data based on a column ID. This works!!

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id']) #where 'id' is the column used to filter
print (df)
```